# Problem while Upgrading web.xml to 2.4 from 2.3

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

I am trying to upgrade my web.xml from 2.3 to 2.4, so I changed my web.xml to something like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 8.1
Servlet 2.4//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_4-1.dtd">-->

<!--
    ===========================================================
                           WUI - WEB.XML
    ===========================================================
--> 

<web-app id="WebApp" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/
    ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <description>Odyssey Web User Interface</description>
    <display-name>wui</display-name>



<!-- Uncomment this when setting up the prevent-multiple-login mechanism -->
<!--
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.xxx.xxxnListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
-->

    <!--  local cache filter setup -->
    <filter> 
      <filter-name>local-cache</filter-name> 
      <filter-class>com.xxx.xxxcheFilter</filter-class> 
   </filter> 
....
```

When I start my Server, I get this error -

> weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
>     problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'servlet-class@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee jsp-file@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'display-name@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element servlet@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:
>     problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'servlet-class@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee jsp-file@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'description@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element servlet@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:

I am using weblogic 10.1 server.

Any idea what else am I supposed to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The structure of your `web.xml` needs to change to pass the new XSD.  For example the new XSD states that your web.xml file should have:

`<servlet-class>` or `<jsp-file>` as an element in the place where you currently have  `<display-name>`

Read the XSD at http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd for more details, it shouldn't take long to restructure so that it passes.

Comment: Thanks Karianna for pointing that out. I iwll change the xml and will post here about the result.

Answer (score 1):

XML Schema definition for Servlet 2.4 uses `<xsd:sequence>` to describe contents of `<servlet>` element, therefore is enforces a specific order of these elements. For example, `<servlet-name>` must be the first child of `<servlet>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me to solve my issue